# Insert a Security Check in the Joomla JForm

Tags: forms, joomla

I have a joomla RSMonial form , and I want to insert an security check like this one

Security Check * .. with an input box,  and something like "Please fill in the sum of 8+7"... instead of a captcha

I'm using Joomla v.1.5.21

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this place : [Joomla! Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/captcha)